# Use Generators as multidimensional array replacement

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, generator

some time ago I built a tool, and got told by some guys to use Generators instead of simple arrays to have better performance etc. I started using Generators, however, googling issues for Generators is pretty useless, since there isn't much information yet for Generators. So, let's come to my question

Let's imagine the following code

```
$array  = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$mapper = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

function mapNumbers($array, $mapper)
{
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        yield $element => $mapper[$element];
    }
}

foreach (mapNumbers($array, $mapper) as $key=>$value) {
    print $key . ' | ' . $value . '<br>';
}
```

This gives the following output

```
0 | zero
1 | one
2 | two
3 | three
4 | four
5 | five
```

However, what I now want to do, is an array that is multidimensional. Let's imagine the following

```
$categories = ['food', 'nonfood'];
$products   = ['food' => ['meat', 'fish'], 'nonfood' => ['table', 'stool']];

function mapCategories($categories, $products)
{
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        yield 'Category' => $category, 'Products' => $products[$category]
    }
}

foreach (mapCategories($categories, $products) as $key=>$value) {
    // do something
}
```

This doesn't work of course, because this line is giving out errors

`yield 'Category' => $category, 'Products' => $products[$category]`

Is what I'm trying to do even possible with Generators? When learning Generators for the first time I thought Generators are there to replace arrays in some circumstances, but it doesn't seem like they replace arrays when trying to build multidimensional arrays.

Is this possible? If yes, how? If no, how would I combine this with Generators? Or is it either only generators or only arrays?

Many thanks

Comment: What output do you actually want to see from your food/non-food example? Do you expect meat, fish, table, stool as four separate responses? What should the key be? food/non-food?

Comment: It is not easily possible with generators prior to PHP7. Then you can use `yield from` to create recursive-style behavior. So, on PHP5 it is still possible, with replacing recursion of calls stack in-place emulation, but I would not do that. Certainly, if it's just to "use generators" - it is a bad idea

Comment: @MarkBaker to be honest, I would like to have the same output as I would've with an array, but instead using yield/generators for that. So, the same output as when I would do `$return[] = ['Category' => $category, 'Products' => $prodcuts[$category]` and after the foreach return that. And I would like to have the same output when using Generators

Comment: @AlmaDo So you recommend going the array way for multidimensional things and "wait" for PHP7 to use generators (at least for multidimensional)

Comment: @Musterknabe only if I got the question correctly and you want to chain nested call for arrays. If that's not the case, then please clarify a but further. If recursion is the goal, then just don't use generators - readability and scalability is much more important than memory issues, so you can use plain array declaration

Comment: To be quite clear, the way you're using generators here is not at all any better than directly iterating over the arrays. Because you have the arrays in memory anyway. A generator like `for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) yield $i;` would be better than an array `[0, 1, 2, ... 999]`, but iterating over a generator which itself just iterates over an array is pretty nonsensical.

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, and your example doesn't really show much need to use a generator, because you already have all the data in your arrays - http://ideone.com/2BeDm1 as my first take on what you want

Comment: Second take on what you might want - http://ideone.com/XueTA1 - but there's still no benefits in using a Generator for this over simply iterating your arrays

Comment: @MarkBaker Yes, my example isn't pretty good, but I can't really post my actual use case, so sorry. Here's a link what I would expect http://ideone.com/lqQxB2

Comment: @deceze I wanted to have a simple example, how I would like it to look. The example I provided isn't a "real" example I'm using. I just wanted to make it as clear as possible. Sorry for the confusiion

Comment: Third guess - http://ideone.com/DrLALg

Comment: @MarkBaker Didn't really test it but your third guess LOOKS like it would be exactly what I need. Didn't think it was that easy :p

Comment: Still not really a sensible case for using generators

Comment: If you want a bit more information about Generators than goes beyond simple Fibonnaci sequences, then take a look at http://www.slideshare.net/MarkBakerUK/generators-49071693

Comment: @MarkBaker In my use case, I'm not doing it like that. Let me explain. I have a page with multiple categories and all categories have products. So now I want to parse the category name and all its products. So before I built an array like this

categoryName => 'Food'
products => products
categoryName => 'NonFood'
products => products

Wouldn't you do that with generators?

Comment: I wouldn't use Generators when you already have the data in arrays, probably just a simple array_map() with a callback to do the mapping.... the benefit of generators is when the base data is being generated directly by the generator, not simply restructured

Comment: Thanks! So, when saving the data in arrays (like phpquery is doing it) I shouldn't yield it. Because it's using arrays, I'm iterating it and then using generators which is more useless than just returning the array. I hope I understood that correctly. Many thanks!

Comment: Something like http://ideone.com/TFUeER (if properly formatted for readability) will be more efficient than using Generators in this case, because for your case the only real benefit is one of readability

Comment: Thanks! If you want, you can answer with the combined message of these comments and I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can use a Generator to achieve what you want:

```
$categories = ['food', 'nonfood'];
$products   = ['food' => ['meat', 'fish'], 'nonfood' => ['table', 'stool']];

function mapCategories($categories, $products) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        yield ['Category' => $category, 'Products' => $products[ $category]];
    }
}

foreach (mapCategories($categories, $products) as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key, ' => '; var_dump($value); echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

There are no real benefits to doing so, other than readability of the code. The real benefit of Generators is when you're actively retrieving/generating the data dynamically, when you gain the memory benefits of only holding the data that you need when it's actually needed, and when it may be faster to do so.
Simply remapping data that you've already loaded into PHP memory doesn't give any speed or memory benefits.

In your case, simply remapping the data using array_map() can provide the merged structure that you want, while still maintaining a good degree of readability:

```
$categories = ['food', 'nonfood'];
$products   = ['food' => ['meat', 'fish'], 'nonfood' => ['table', 'stool']];

foreach (
    array_map(
        function ($value) use ($products) {
            return ['Category' => $value, 'Products' => $products[$value]];
        },
        $categories
    ) as $value) {
        var_dump($value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is as follows :

```
$categories = ['food', 'nonfood'];
$products   = ['food' => ['meat', 'fish'], 'nonfood' => ['table', 'stool']];

function mapCategories($categories, $products)
{
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            yield $category => $product;
        }
    }
}

# OR 

function mapCategories($categories, $products)
{
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        yield $category => $products[$category];
    }
}
```